# ran rm -r /* now almost everything is deleted can i recover it?

Tags: server

root@ / () $ history
-bash: history: /home/lavelle/.bash_history: cannot create: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/bin/colrm: No such file or directory

is there any way to recover it?

Comment: First thing to do is immediately hold down power button for 10 seconds to power off. Then get live USB, boot with it and install recovery programs. See the duplicate question.

Comment: Recovery is best by putting whatever backup strategy you put into place, into action. Why are you asking us?  We don't know what backup strategy and thus what recovery plan applies.  We don't even know what OS & release, nor what product you're using.   Data recovery tools may make up for failings in your implemented backup strategy.

Answer (score 2):

You have destroyed your system.

Some files may be recoverable, but restoring your entire system is no longer possible.

Stop using the hard drive that you want to recover files from. Look up how to [use the Testdisk and Photorec applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files) for self-service data recovery.

If your files are valuable to you, consider a paid data recovery service rather than mucking about with self-service.

Once you have an available disk again, you must install a new operating system on your hardware.

Comment: it was a vm on digital ocean